# How do you go from $|3-\frac{x}{3}|<\epsilon$ to $|\frac{x}{3}-3|<\epsilon$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-explanation

The first part of the solution provided on Quizlet with regards to proving the statement $\lim_{x\rightarrow9}(1-\frac{1}{3}x)=-2$ using the $\epsilon$, $\delta$ definition of a limit, states;
\begin{align}
|f(x)-L|<\epsilon&\Rightarrow\left|\left[1-\frac{x}{3}\right]-(-2)\right|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow\left|1-\frac{x}{3}+2\right|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow\left|3-\frac{x}{3}\right|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow\left|\frac{x}{3}-3\right|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{1}{3}\left|x-9\right|<\epsilon\\
&\Rightarrow\left|x-9\right|<3\epsilon
\end{align}
I don't see how you can go from $|3-\frac{x}{3}|<\epsilon$ to $|\frac{x}{3}-3|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Becaue $|a -b| = |b-a|$.  Always.

Comment: Using the fact that $\left|3-\frac x3\right|=\left|\frac x3-3\right|$?

Comment: Note that $|x|=|-x|$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$; in your case, $|3-x/3|=|-(3-x/3)|=|-3+x/3|=|x/3-3|$.

Comment: I suppose if you need details $|\frac x3 - 3| = |-3 + \frac x3|=|-1\cdot(3-\frac x3)|= |-1|\cdot |3-\frac x3| = 1\cdot |3-\frac x3| = |3-\frac x3| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always the case that $\vert -z \vert = \vert z \vert$.  Just apply that principle to $z= 3- \frac x3$.